# why css not loaded in React production build says wrong mime/type

Tags: node.js, reactjs

**Server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path')
var app = express();
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'build')));

app.get('/*',(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'index.html'));
})

app.listen(PORT,()=>{
    console.log("server started at 8000");
})
```

1. React works fine in development mode.

2. in console in html file their is href to css file

link type="text/css" id="dark-mode" rel="stylesheet" href(unknown)>

3. I had edited homepage before build

Comment: This is most likely a problem with how your server is serving static files

Comment: what does it mean. Is their other method to serve too

Comment: Can you check (in the network tab of the inspector) if the MIME type (look for `content-type: `) is actually `text/css`?

Comment: it is stylesheet but it contain html code,but actual file contain css code

Comment: What do you mean? Is the content of the file not what you expect?

Comment: yes it is html in css stylesheet